# Loading message on form

Tags: c#, winforms

I've put a loading message like this on my form :

```
public void myFunc()
{
    lbl_status.Text = "Loading ... Please Wait";
    // Some Database Works
    lbl_status.Text = "Done";
}
```

but there is a problem. Some times when I click on the button ( Which does `myFunc` method ) my application doesn't show the Loading message. It just does the database work than it will show Done message.
I know that sometimes the database work is very fast so Loading message won't show but sometimes it is not that fast, like the fist time I open my app. At that time my application seems to be disabled and no buttons and no textBoxes and ... works and after the database work it will be OK and show Done message and never shows Loading message again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do your db work in background thread:

```
public void myFunc()
{
    lbl_status.Text = "Loading ... Please Wait";
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

EDIT: oops DB works should be in the DoWork event handler :)

```
void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Some Database Works
}

void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    lbl_status.Text = "Done";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your application, like all Windows GUI application, needs to process the GUI events. It is these events that do things like refresh the labels and make your application seem 'responsive'. See [Window Messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381405%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Your winforms application runs the message loop when you call [`Application.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157902%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Begins running a standard application message loop on the current thread

If you block the processing while waiting for database work then it will stop refreshing and it will be unresponsive (not respond to clicks or keyboard). So you have to do your database w/o blocking the main loop. There are several options:

- use a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
- use [`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
- use the async database methods like [`SqlCommand.BeginExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.beginexecutereader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and completion callbacks
- use await methods like [`SqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh204836%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Each method has pros and cons, the easiest to start with is probably the first one. Be aware that from a background thread, or from a completion callback, you *must* use the [`Control.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) when interacting with the main GUI (ie. when updating the form or any element on it).

Answer (score 1):

Any updates to UI objects must be done on the UI thread.

You should look into Control.Invoke to provide you a way to put your call on the Display thread the Control is on.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

for further clarification, this also means that your heavy updates should be done on a background thread.

WorkerThread may be a good solution for you.